# How can I delete data from a sequential file while it is being appended by another process

Tags: c++

I'm reading data from a file in a sequential manner while the same file is being appended data by another process. So far so good. My trouble comes when I need to delete from the file the data that I have already retrieved, which I have to do in order to prevent the file from getting too large due to the writing process. I don't need to delete exactly the data that I have just retrieved, but at least do some removal periodically without losing any data that have not already been read. How can I do this with C++?

I understand that there may be different valuable approaches. I'd check as valid answer any that would prove useful to my developing the code.

Comment: There's no standard approach with the current c++ standard yet. May be such stuff can be handled with the c++17 file system approach properly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'm not asking for a standard approach but for some approach to doing this task with the "regular" C++ language resources for streams management -- if this is at all feasible "within reason".

Comment: _"I'm not asking for a standard approach but for some approach to doing this task with the "regular" C++ language resources for streams management "_ No there isn't any _standard approach_. You need to interact with the particular operating system capabilities (file exclusive locking, change file watching, etc.).

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your point right. Do you mean any "standard C++ approach" as opposed to any "C++ standard approach"? If this so, you might consider answering in that way and, if no one comes with an alternative in some time, I'll check your answer as valid. By the way, do you know if this is this the reason why my question has been downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

This is not just a matter of C++, any language you use it will at some point (in its runtime, standard library implementation, interpreter or whatever its architecture is) use the system calls that the system provides for file handling (e.g. `open()`, `read()`, `write()`).

I'm not aware of any system call that will delete parts of a file or replace parts with something else (you can position yourself somewhere in the middle of the file and start overwriting its contents, but this will be a byte for byte change, you can't change a piece of it with another piece with a different size). There are all sorts of workarounds for simulating deleting or changing parts of a file, but nothing that does it directly. For example: read from the original file, write only what you want to keep in a temporary file, remove the original and rename the temporary. But this will not work in your situation if the writing process keeps the file open.

Another approach would be something inspired by [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate): when the file gets to a certain maximum size it gets switched with a new one, and you can process the previous one as you want. This approach does require changes in the writing process also.

Comment: Your answer is very informative and helpful in that way, but I'm afraid I cannot switch to a different file as you suggest because the writing process is attached to it in a way that prevents me from doing so without losing data. Actually, and just as you point out, changes to the writing process would be needed, but the scenario does not enable me to access the process itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the file length at the beginning, then start writing in it and when you reach your end of file, you just start writing at the beginning of the file again. But you should make sure that read pointer doesn't pass the writing pointer.

Comment: But then I would lose data because I cannot stop or even pause the writing process. Or, do you conceive of any approach to doing as you suggest while not losing data? As I said in my comment to lonut's answer, I cannot act on the writing process, which is attached to the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to emulate the behavior of a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) using a regular file. This would require special support from your operating system, which probably doesn't exist because you should be using named pipes instead. Named pipes are a special kind of file which is used for communication between two processes. Like regular files, it has a path, has a filename and exist on disk. However, where a regular file's contents are stored on disk, the contents of a named pipe only exists in memory and only that data that has been written, but not yet read. This is exactly what you're trying to do.

Assuming you're using a unix based OS. you can run `mkfifo outputfile` and then use `outputfile` for reading and appending. No C++ code required, though if you want you can also call [`mkfifo()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) from your c++ code.

If you're using Windows, it all becomes a bit more complicated. You have to specify something like `\\.\pipe\outputfile` as the filename for reading and appending.